# Formula cell reference increment

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to figure out how to increment an excel formula down column F starting at cell F2.  I created a for loop, but unfortunately this just increments F2, to F3, to F4 and writes the same exact formula into each cell without incrementing the cell reference.  For instance the formula is ='C2-E2' and what I would like it to do is increment so when its placed in cell F3 it would change to '='C3-E3', and when placed into F4 it changes to '=C4-E4'.

```
import openpyxl as xl
import os
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell


input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NNM'
Summary = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\Summary.xlsx'
newFile = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\Comparison.xlsx'

files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]

i=0
ii=0

wb3=xlsxwriter.Workbook(newFile)
ws3=wb3.add_worksheet('Comparison')

format = wb3.add_format()
format.set_align('center')
format.set_align('vcenter')
format.set_bold(True)
format.set_font_size(14)
format.set_bg_color('#C9C9C9')
format.set_border(style=1)

for row_num in range(1,50):
       cell = xl_rowcol_to_cell(row_num,5)
       formula = '=C2-E2'
       ws3.write(row_num,5,formula)

ws3.write_row("A1:Q1", ['TNAME','Start Segment','Start Chainage(ft)','Start Segment','Start Chainage(ft)','Start Chainage Difference(ft)','End Segment','End Chainage(ft)','End Segment','End Chainage(ft)','End Chainage Difference(ft)','Stops','Stops','Distance','Distance','Distance Difference (ft)','Comments'], format)
ws3.set_column(1, 17, 35)
wb3.close()

wb3 = xl.load_workbook(newFile)
ws3 = wb3.worksheets[0]

wb2 = xl.load_workbook(Summary)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]

for file in files:
   input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
   wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
   ws1=wb1.worksheets[0]

   series = pd.read_excel(file,usecols = "F",squeeze = True)
   counts = series.value_counts()
   z = counts[0]/2

   ws3[f'A{i+2}']=ws1['A1'].value[28:]
   ws3[f'D{i+2}']=ws1['B4'].value
   ws3[f'E{i+2}']=ws1['D4'].value
   ws3[f'I{i+2}']=ws1['B'][-1].value
   ws3[f'J{i+2}']=ws1['D'][-1].value
   ws3[f'O{i+2}']=ws1['E'][-1].value
   ws3[f'N{i+2}']=ws2[f'I{ii+6}'].value
   ws3[f'M{i+2}']=z

   i += 1
   ii +=1

   wb3.save(newFile)
```

Comment: What is the problem? Also please try to make the code [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As mentioned above the for loop is not changing the cell reference in my code.  As the formula is incremented down column F I would like the formula to change the cell reference.  The formula starts in cell F2 and is '=C2-E2", but when the script increments to F3 it copies the same formula '=C2-E2' and I would like this to change to '=C3-E3' and then when it increments to F4 the formula would change to '=C4-E4.  The problem as mentioned above is that the formula isn't changing the cell reference.  I end up with F2 '=C2-E2', F3 '=C2-E2', F4 '=C2-E2'.

Comment: Really consider to make the code [minimal], there is plenty of code (e.g. styling of cells) completely irrelevant to your issue, making difficult to focus on the problem.

Comment: In the code, you have `formula = '=C2-E2'; ws3.write(row_num,5,formula)`. Why not put the correct numbers here, instead of hardcoded `C2` and `E2`?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. I updated the for loop to this:  for row_num in range(1,30):
    ws3.write_formula(row_num - 1, 5,
                            '=C%d + $E%d' % (row_num, row_num))